# TFS 2013 Retention Policy Not Working

Tags: tfs, build, policy, retention

I created a build definition using the TFS 2013 build process template "TfvcTemplate.12.xaml". I'm using the default retention policy, which is to keep the latest 10 builds. However, nothing gets deleted in my drop location and in my TFS history. Builds just keep on accumulating. Could anyone give me pointers on how to troubleshoot this?

Tks

[Policies configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcZdp.png)

[Build history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUsmL.png)

Comment: How many builds in the Build Explorer of VS? Are they have the same build result? You can provide a screenshot here. Can you reproduce that issue with a new build definition?

Comment: Hi, the retention policies are set to keep 10 latest, but there's more than this. Please, check the edition I made on the original post with the images. TKS

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a new build definition? Are the builds in other team projects have the same issue?

Comment: Yes, with a new build definition, the problem persists. I have only one team project. It's important to say that I can delete the builds manually whitout problems

Comment: Are there other build process templates? Try it with this template: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AresBGZVYryjhSg4r178BXMyh0eH